# how to get the size of a parameter/number in bits?

Tags: verilog

I want to create an array in Verilog with a size based on a number of parameters.
I tried this code in ModelSim, but I got the following error:

> Parameter value must be constant.

```
localparam a = 250;
localparam b = 480;
localparam m = a * 100 / (b * 2);
localparam s = $bits(2 * m);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To calculate the number of bits needed to hold the value in verilog you can use the `$clog2` function. something like the following will provide the number of bits for `2 * m`.  The only caveat is when m == 0. You need at least one bit to hold `0`.

```
localparam s = m == 0 ? 1 : $clog2(2 * m);
```

Answer (score 0):

It help when you give [complete runnable examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with the command used to run the example.

```
module top;
   localparam a  = 250;
   localparam b      = 480;
   localparam m      = a * 100 / (b * 2);
   localparam s      = $bits(2 * m);
endmodule

vlog file.v
```

`$bits` is not defined in Verilog, so the compiler thinks this is a user defined run-time function. You won't get that error if you change the file extension to `.sv`.

Comment: $bits always returns the size of the variable/parameter, 32 in this case for an int parameter.

Comment: You're right. I wasn't looking at the computation they were trying to achieve, just the error.